# Convergence of series: determining limit

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm self-studying analysis from some notes that a university here have put up, and it contains a great many tests and criterias for determining when a series $\sum a_n$, or $\sum f_n(x)$, is convergent or divergent... and that's all fine, but I don't see any theorem telling me how to determine **what it converges towards?**,

The only one I've seen such a theorem for is the geometric series, but what about all the other ones? Do we have a theorem telling us how to explicitly determine the value/function something converges towards? If not, what methods are commonly used?

I looked up on the internet and found that $$\ln{x+1} = \sum_0^\infty  (-1)^n \frac{x^{n-1}}{n-1}$$ so if I wanted to show this, what would I do? Or are questions like these too advanced for someone whose just been introduced to series for the first time?

Comment: You should write $\log (x+1).$ Also, that series should be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}x^n/n.$

Comment: Proving that a series converges (if it does) is vastly easier than finding the limit. There is no (known) way to find the limit of an arbitrary series.

Comment: Your example series is of the so-called entire type (polynomial of unbounded degree). These can sometimes be identified to analytical functions be taking the termwise derivatives or antiderivatives, and a few other tricks. Take a look at what happens if you derive yours once.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that
$$
\frac{1}{1 + t} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n t^n
$$

and the convergence is uniform in the interval $[0,x]$ for $|x|<1$.

Hence, you can integrate termwise and you get
$$
\log(1 + x) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{n + 1}}{n + 1}
$$